# Executing a command line

Tags: ruby, siri

I want to add some lines in my siriproxy server to be able to control my home automation system with an x10 cm19a.

I found my command line to make it work and when I run it in the terminal an example everything works fine:

```
karl@karl:~$ ./x10cmd rf a5 off
```

I tried to add this line to my siriproxy script while doing this:

```
  listen_for /turn the bedroom light on/i do
    exec('./x10cmd rf a5 on')
    say "i turn your light on"

    request_complete
```

It is working, but it stops my siriproxy from running, so I've tried:

```
  listen_for /turn the bedroom light on/i do
    `ls ./x10cmd rf a5 on`
    say "i turn your light on"

    request_complete
```

and

```
  listen_for /turn the bedroom light on/i do
    system('ls ./x10cmd rf a5 on')
    say "i turn your light on"

    request_complete
```

But nothing is working. It keeps saying:

> ls cannot found directory.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

In your second and third tries, you have an `ls` at the beginning of the command line.

Comment: Expanding on the answer, `ls ./x10cmd rf a5 on` in both tries is the offending line. That's because the `ls` command can't find a file or directory called `./x10cmd`. Remove the `ls` to fix the problem.